# How to get distinct nodes for a view and its attachments?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view of type "block" showing 1 node and another display attached to that block showing 3 nodes, in both displays nodes are sorted randomly, the problem is that I can't find the way to add a "distinct" for both views, so sometimes both displays show the same node because of the random sorting

Is there any way to solve it?

EDIT: I've posted an image with the real view, has you can see in this case first and the third nodes are duplicated, sometimes it happends because i need them to show randomly

[image]

Comment: Do you WANT them to be shown in random order? If not, have you defined a Sort Criteria for both views?  If you use a sort criteria, you can use an Offset of 1 for the block showing the 3 nodes to avoid repeating the first node, shown in the other view.

Comment: @argiepiano i already have offest 1 in my attachment, but i need them randomly, so sometimes i get duplicated nodes between block and its attachments

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a block for the top node, and an attachment for the lower 3 (like you are using now), I would use just one block (or page) that shows only 4 nodes, chosen at random with `Global: Random` as a Sort criteria (you can specify only 4 items to be shown by changing the `Use pager:` option).

THEN I would override the the `Style output` template file for the block (in `Theme: Information` in the `Advanced` area) to style the output of the block, for example by defining two divs, one for the top node, and one that wraps the 3 nodes below. Then use CSS to tweak the presentation (for example, floating left the bottom 3 nodes)

There are many good tutorials on overriding views templates, for example [here](https://www.interworks.com/blog/carmstrong/2013/02/27/quick-tutorial-overriding-drupal-views-using-templates).

Comment: Yep i use them all the time, i just wanted to know if i could do this by dashboard, i used to do everything by template but now i'm trying to use as less as i can. Guess i'll have to use them haha thanks. However i'll be checking that thread in case that someone figure it out

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve you requirement by following below steps.

1. Under view **Advance** setting, click on **Query settings**.
2. Now select **Distinct** checkbox.

[image]

Comment: I always use it but, has i said, i need to distinct nodes between a block and its attachments. I've posted an image to clarify my question

Comment: @Nikhil, using distinct control single view but problem domain is to keep distinct results of two different views.